# How to view SVN UP changes before actually applying it

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I cannot remember how to do this.. I basically want to run svn up but before I do this want to see what it will change before I apply this..any ideas of how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it..
svn st -u

To view the upcoming changes :)